# Android launcher not started

Tags: android

I am making an application which will run automatically on phone start up. 
Now when i install my app on phone and restart the phone here i have an option to start the launcher or to start my app.
 and in the last there is a check box saying "Use by default for this section."
 By mistake i checked the check box and start my application. There was a bug in my app so getting "Force to close" message again and again. and now i even can't start my phone. 
Plz help me . I want to launch my launcher. How could i do this? Please help me.....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi connect to your device from adb and uninstall your app

adb uninstall ----your package name---

or fix a bug and try to execute from eclipse 
Good luck